# Understanding HTTP in Angular 2 tutorial

Tags: http, angular

I've been going through the Angular 2 [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) tutorial and I'm not understanding the [lesson on using HTTP](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) to fetch data from a service.

In this lesson in the Hero Service a variable `heroesUrl` is declared as 'app/heroes'.

```
  private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

The data is declared in the in-memory-data service as a static array:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice (api)' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' },
      { id: 21, name: 'Mister Man' }
    ];
    return { heroes };
  }
}
```

But in the routing module 'heroes' (which I assume is the same as 'app/heroes') points to the HeroesComponent.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'detail/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroesComponent }
];
```

In the HeroesComponent the `getHeroes()` function calls the `this.heroService.getHeroes()` function:

```
  getHeroes(): void {
    //Result of heroService.getHeroes is a Promise
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroesresult => this.heroes = heroesresult);
  }
```

On the surface it looks like `HeroesComponent.getHeroes()` calls `HeroService.getHeroes()` which then does a `http.get` back to the HeroesComponent, not to the data source.

It all works for me (like magic) but there is no explanation of how the data which is in the in-memory-data service is fetched by the call from HeroesService to `this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)`.

Could somebody please help me understand?

Comment: `private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api`, that just a simulation url, when you develop your own app, just replace that url by your url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not magic.

What's happening is you're calling a get request to a in memory api !

Have a look at [in-memory-api](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api)

Basically , the class InMemoryDataService , extends from a InMemoryDbService which creates a in memory api observable .

Think of it as a stub that has been created on the fly and then when you call get method the call will be redirected to that package (via xhrbackend) and then you get that hero list . .

Comment: Aaah, I think I get it now. Thanks @xe4me.

Answer (score 1):

The 'app/heroes' URL is not referring to the routing module 'heroes'.  It is referring to the heroes data object in in-memory-data-service.ts.  So it is not magic; the URL is just referring to a data object, not a path.

The documentation at https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 is too terse to be clear and I've made suggestions for what needs to be improved at https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3559